# How to fix small wobble in rear wheel?

Tags: maintenance, brakes, rear-wheel

My rear tire has a small wobble that I have not been able to get rid of.

When you put the bike on its back, and spin the rear wheel you can notice that it moves about 3mm to one side once every rotation. The small wobble causes series discomfort when braking from high speeds (I have disk brakes) since it makes it feel as if I am braking hard once per rotation causing me to jerk back and forwards a bit.

Any idea on how to fix this?

I have taken the wheel off and ensured that it was correctly aligned, yet this did not help.

Comment: Odd - at first I thought the wheel rim was out of true, but that should be having no effect on your disk brakes.  Is the rotor flat ?  Use a steel ruler to check that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trueing front bicycle wheel](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46481/trueing-front-bicycle-wheel)

Comment: You should never ever put a bicycle on its back! Apart from that have you checked the seating of the tyre and if the wobble doesn't come from the axle bearings.

Comment: "You should never ever put a bicycle on its back!" Why not? Not everyone has a repair stand or even the space for one. What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: I would also disagree with the part to not put your bike on its back. Apart from that as said before check if the axle might be the problem. If this is not the case, get the pressure of the tire and flex the tire properly so that it will seat correctly in the rim. Afterwards get a bit of air pressure inside and flex it again. If this should not fix the problem try another tire perhaps.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem turning a bike upside down, but putting bars and saddle on a surface that could damage them is not recommended.

Comment: When you say the wheel was "correctly aligned", do you mean you had it checked on a truing stand and there was no wobble? Because what you describe certainly sounds like a wheel out of true. Also check that the periodic resistance is not from the tire actually rubbing the frame or something.

Comment: @David Richerby : Because it means damage to saddle, handlebars, stem, brake levers and bar tape, that's why you should never put a bike upside down. And even if you don't own a stand you can always hang it by a rope, a belt or similar from above.

Comment: I don't have anything to hang it from. And what damage is going to occur indoors?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback. From reading you'll's responses, I think I figured out what is wrong with it. It seems to be out of true, yet since I do not have a truing stand I will take it to my local bike shop so that they can correct it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Because you said you have disk brakes, it is unlikely that the unevenness is in the rim/tire. It must be something at the hub. Because you said it is visible at the rim, it is not a bent brake disk (unless you have both rim and disk bent). It is also unlikely to be loose bearing cups, though I would have checked them as well. When the wheel is not rotating, try to wobble it sideways with your hand. If it does wobble, tune up the hub.

The last possibility is that the wheel's axle does not sit properly in the dropouts, i.e. it is not installed correctly as the whole unit. Loosen the quick release skewer or nuts that hold the wheel and make sure that you've pressed it all the way in the frame's dropouts before closing skewer or tightening the nuts again.